# Overbooking expected profit

Tags: probability, expectation, binomial-distribution

A man has a hotel with 30 rooms but he offers 32 rooms because 10% of people who booked a room won't show up.

a) Probability, that there will be overbookings:
P(31 people show up) + P(32 people show up) = $ \binom{32}{31} * 0.9^{31} * 0.1^1  + \binom{32}{32} * 0.9^{32}*0.1^0 = 0.16$. This is pretty easy.

b) Calculate the expected profit if $X$ means the number of overbooked rooms and the profit is described via the function $Prof(X) = 4800 - 500X$.
I don't know how to solve this. I tried to somehow distinguish between $X=0$ and $X\gt0$, but it doesn't work out. The solution should be 4705.

c) Should he offer 30, 31, 32 or 33 beds to maximize the expected profit?

Thanks.

Comment: c) is unrealistic as the profit function *as stated* is clearly maximized when $X$ cannot be positive (i.e., when at most 30 rooms are offered). But in reality, underbooking (or no-show) would of course also be detrimental ...Are you sure you copied the profit function correctly?

Comment: Yes I think so. He gets 150€ for each booking (no matter if he shows up or not). For each overbooking he has to pay 500€ because he must find another expensive hotel. The solution says 32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that I will help you.

b) Probability that there will be exactly one overbooking is ${{32}\choose{31}} \cdot 0.9^{31} \cdot 0.1 = 0.122$ and probability that there will be 2 overbookings is $0.9^{32} = 0.034$ (as you correctly stated in a)). This means that probability that $X = 1$ is 0.122, probability that $X = 2$ is 0.034 and probability for $X = 0$ (no overbooking) is $1 - 0.122 - 0.034 = 0.844$. So the expected profit is $EX = 0.844*4800 + 0.122*4300 + 0.034*3800 = 4705$.

I gave you the hint how to calculate expected profit also for 30, 31 and 33 beds which is required in c). Are you able to do so or should I help you more?

Comment: Thank you - I was actually trying out a smililar solution before but I stopped because I thought it was not correct.

For c: I guess I first have to compute:
$\binom{33}{30+x} * 0.9^{30+x}* 0.1^{3-x}$ and then use the formula to compute the profit.

Comment: Yes, if you consider room with 33 beds.

Comment: Okay, and I also have to do this for 32 beds, for 31 beds and for 30 beds I know the profit will be 4800.

Comment: I think I managed to solve this. For everyone who is interested, here is the Excel-Sheet I created: http://wikisend.com/download/581596/HW2_5.ods

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!